# AWS API Gateway mapping templates exception handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, vtl

I am looking to encapsulate the mapping template codes in a try catch to prevent the gateway from crashing.
I wrote some complex logging algorithm to parse the request and body and log wanted parameters and cannot guarantee that it will work 100% of the time.
Ideally I am looking for something like
#try{
mapping templates codes
} #catch(just ignore it)
I've done a bit of research and it seems the only way for error handling is to either parse the response body or approach it with Lamda.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: VTL doesn't have anything like a try/catch out of the box, and you can't add one to AWS API Gateway since you don't control the VTL engine.

I think your best bet is going to be validating input as much as possible.